# How to get user credentials using email

Tags: php, email

Is there a way on how to get the first name, last name, age, gender etc. of a user by just inputting his/her email address? I want to do it in php. Any suggestions are accepted.

Comment: Do have a set of data? How is that structured?

Comment: Think. Does you email-address contain your name, your age, your gender, etc? An email-address is nowhere stored in public.

Comment: It is possible, dunno why it is down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API available for that, that is [FullContact](http://fullcontact.com). You can signup for free and use a free API. There are also demos on how to use it, it is like the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: Check the output, you can have it in JSON format. Just use `curl` if you want to use it in PHP.